# Take XML Value From API and Display It On Webpage

Tags: javascript, xml, api

So, this might infuriate a few (a lot) of you, but I recently decided to use my very patchy knowledge of JavaScript to attempt to do something with a casual project. I have little experience with JavaScript or any other object-oriented language and figured I could cobble something together with online tutorials and what I had picked up working on earlier projects.

Basically, using [this api](http://www.nationstates.net/cgi-bin/api.cgi?region=Pluviostan&q=delegate), I want to take the "delegate" value and display it on a webpage.

This is what I have so far, and, as you can probably gather, it isn't working out too well:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
  var Connect = new XMLHttpRequest();

  Connect.open("GET", "https://www.nationstates.net/cgi-bin/api.cgi?region=pluviostan", false);
  Connect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
  Connect.send(null);

  var xmlDoc= Connect.responseXML;

  var Region= xmlDoc.childNodes[0];

  var Delegate= Region.getElementsByTagName("Delegate");

  document.write("<p></p>");
   document.write(Delegate[0].textContent.toString());
  }
</script>
```

As it stands now, nothing displays. I get nadda. Could anybody lend a hand?

I realize that this is, without question, a case of "trying to run before you can walk", but at the moment I don't have the time to actively try to learn, and I've only ever wanted to do a handful of very specific things anyway. Rest assured though, once I have more time, I'll start dedicating time to learning how to properly code, instead of patching together these horrific Frankenstein things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this. btw `Region.getElementsByTagName("Delegate");` "Delegate" - should be UPPERCASED

```js
$(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.nationstates.net/cgi-bin/api.cgi?region=Pluviostan&q=delegate",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data){    
      var xml = $(data);
      var delegate  = xml.find("DELEGATE");
      $("#result").html(delegate.text()); 
    }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="result">
</p>
```